# UART communication in Linux kernel module

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I am programming Linux kernel module for communication with device connected through UART, but I don't know how to access UART from kernel module. I don't want to write my own UART driver, I would like to use the existing one and only add communication layer for my device. I saw something similiar done in userspace-like manner, however I read that kernel modules should not access files like that. I am wondering if it could be done using existing driver's structs and functions, because that's how I have already programmed module, which used I2C. Example of a module reading from UART would be very useful.

Comment: What is the reason you want to make a kernel module? Why can't you communicate with the device through the serial port from a user-space program?

Comment: I want to create files for my device in /dev and /sys.

Comment: So you kind of want a *virtual* device which does some translation from the actual device (or similar)? Translations could be done with a user-space proxy which I think would be a better idea (as it doesn't clutter up kernel-space or introduce possible new security issues), but I see your point.

Comment: Yes, basically I want something like that. I will consider using userspace proxy, but I am still interested, how the UART communication could be done in kernel module.